# Referencing an integer in an edittext view in the android xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, r.java-file

How do you reference integers from the strings.xml file in an edittext view? I am simplying trying to add integers into a cell of a table row. When I run the app, I get the errors referenced in the below R.Java file.

**R.java File**

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int 1=0x7f090001;
    public static final int 10=0x7f09000a;
    public static final int 11=0x7f09000b;
    public static final int 12=0x7f09000c;
    public static final int 13=0x7f09000d;
    public static final int 14=0x7f09000e;
    public static final int 15=0x7f09000f;
    public static final int 16=0x7f090010;
    public static final int 17=0x7f090011;
    public static final int 18=0x7f090012;
    public static final int 2=0x7f090002;
    public static final int 3=0x7f090003;
    public static final int 4=0x7f090004;
    public static final int 5=0x7f090005;
    public static final int 6=0x7f090006;
    public static final int 7=0x7f090007;
    public static final int 8=0x7f090008;
    public static final int 9=0x7f090009;
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f090013;
    public static final int expandableListView=0x7f090000;
}
```

**Strings.XML File**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">GI</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <item type="integer" name="one">1</item>
    <item type="integer" name="two">2</item>
    <item type="integer" name="three">3</item>
    <item type="integer" name="four">4</item>
    <item type="integer" name="five">5</item>
    <item type="integer" name="six">6</item>
    <item type="integer" name="seven">7</item>
    <item type="integer" name="eight">8</item>
    <item type="integer" name="nine">9</item>
    <item type="integer" name="ten">10</item>
    <item type="integer" name="eleven">11</item>
    <item type="integer" name="twelve">12</item>
    <item type="integer" name="thirteen">13</item>
    <item type="integer" name="fourteen">14</item>
    <item type="integer" name="fifteen">15</item>
    <item type="integer" name="sixteen">16</item>
    <item type="integer" name="seventeen">17</item>
    <item type="integer" name="eighteen">18</item>




</resources>
```

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/1"
            android:text="1"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/2"
            android:text="2"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/3"
            android:text="3"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/4"
            android:text="4"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/5"
            android:text="5"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/6"
            android:text="6"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/7"
            android:text="7"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/8"
            android:text="8"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/9"
            android:text="9"
            android:padding="10dp"/>


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/10"
            android:text="10"
            android:padding="10dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/11"
            android:text="11"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/12"
            android:text="12"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/13"
            android:text="13"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/14"
            android:text="14"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/15"
            android:text="15"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/16"
            android:text="16"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/17"
            android:text="17"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/18"
            android:text="18"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: IDs can't start with numbers.

Comment: `How do you reference integers from the strings.xml file` You reference Strings by their name: **R.string.one**; `<item type="integer" name="one">1</item>` => `<string name="one">1</string>`. Or set the integers (like `<item type="integer" name="one">1</item>`) into the `integers.xml` file. Then Reference them as **R.integer.one**.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking that the IDs cant be numbers or start with numbers because this generates variables in java whose names are numbers (bad) or start with numbers (bad)

So, change

```
android:id="@+id/1"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/one"
```

for example

Answer (score 2):

```
@+id/1
```

generates

```
public static final int 1=0x7f090001;
```

which is forbidden in Java. Which is why your `ids` cannot start with a number.